# Windows-to-Windows SSH: Get remote environment variable

Tags: windows, ssh, environment-variables

From a Windows 10 host I connect to a Windows 10 target machine via SSH to read one of its environment variables, say, `%COMPUTERNAME%`. OpenSSH is installed on both machines. The remote shell is cmd, and I'd like to use **cmd** commands. I tried this:

```
ssh someuser@somecomputer echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

Unfortunately I get the host computer's name. Apparently the local cmd substitutes the local `%COMPUTERNAME%` variable before sending the command to the target. How can I get the remote computer's name? I tried escaping the `%`, using quotes etc., but nothing helped.

IMPORTANT: *I can already solve the problem by calling PowerShell on the target. What I'd like to learn is how this can be done using cmd... I have a feeling this should be possible :)*

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for delayed variable expansion https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: To add regarding delayed expansion... this is not the use case for it. In batch file when e.g. using FOR loop variables are resolved at start, yet you might be changing them during for loop and if you need to work with this changing value inside the same for loop, that would be nice example of delayed expansion need as it will resolve at the time it is used/accessed and not cached prior to it - yet this question is only about proper escaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093525/how-to-setx-without-expanding-variables)), the `%` character must be escaped. I tried this previously, but didn't know the escape character is different depending on *where* you want to do the escaping:

1. In the command line:

```
ssh someuser@somecomputer echo ^%COMPUTERNAME^%
```

2. In a batch file:

```
ssh someuser@somecomputer echo %%COMPUTERNAME%%
```

(I also tried @Robert's suggestion, the delayed variable expansion, but couldn't make it work.)

Comment: Glad I could passively assist with your issue.